# ApplicationPoolIdentity or Local Services privileges

Tags: iis, identity

IIS 7.5 has new inbuilt identity called ApplicationPoolIdentity. IIS takes care of authentication and avoiding interference of other process running into Network Services.
I would like to know whether ApplicationPoolIdentity has more permissions or Local Services.
As per my understanding  Local System has got higher privilege, then Network Service and Local Services then minimum privileges are given to ApplicationPoolIdentity.
But then if you are running your IIS application in ApplicationPoolIdentity then it can access network resources.
Can you please clarify which is with minimum privileges??

Thanks
Keshav